# How can I run rtsp example with vlcj?

Tags: java, streaming, rtsp, vlcj

I want to compile `StreamRtsp` example, I do something like pic1 and pic2 (in the below picture) and compile is the last picture, I don't know what is wrong, how can I run `StreamRtsp` correctly? Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Inlined image, improved grammar

Comment: Please add the code to the question as text, not as an image, and explain what you've tried to do in order to debug.